# Django reference a Model by foreign key or a different field

Tags: python, django, model, django-rest-framework, serialization

I am using Django REST Framework. I have two models, Sites and Statuses.

```py
class Sites(models.Model):
    site_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Statuses, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
```

```py
class Statuses(models.Model):
    status_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'Statuses'
```

I would like to be able to perform a GET on sites, and have the Statuses.description field returned (instead of Statuses.status_id). Also, I would like it so that either status_id or description may be used interchangeably in a POST to create a new site. Where does this type of functionality belong (serializer, models, etc...)?

I know I can accomplish the first part of my question by adding a property to the Sites model and then referencing this field in the Sites serializer.

```py
@property
def status(self):
    return self.row_status.description
```

However I thought the convention of a Model is that it should be a 1:1 representation of the database table. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This fits well in the serializer, like this:

```
class SitesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    description = serializers.CharField(source='status.description')

    class Meta:
        model = Sites
        fields = ('site_id', 'description')
```

(But the `status` field should probably not have `null=True` set.)

Comment: This answers the first part of my question, and is a much better than using a @property in the model. However, It does not solve the second part of the question which is: Is there a way to POST a new site and reference status by either an integer (id) or string (description)?